# Order of pre-processing the dataset

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, categorical-encoding, data-preprocessing, smote

suppose I have categorical dataset, I'm doing data pre-processing.
what is the correct order of applying these 3 techniques

- Train Test split
- SMOTEN to over sampler the minority class
- Categorical encoding of variables (a mix of one hot, label encoding and target encoding)

Comment: Why do you want to oversample the minority class? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While one hot and label encoding can be applied dataframe wise before splitting (using e.g. pandas routines), it's better to split first and build a proper pipeline which would simplify the input of the new data without extra manual steps.

Target encoding should always be done after splitting, otherwise it creates a huge target leakage.

Same applies to augmentation: you want your test set to represent the production data, not the altered data. (Worth noting using this for resampling is often suboptimal, consider the sources mentioned in the [metathread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349)).

imblearn SMOTEN implementation expects categorical features only iirc, so it should come before encoding.

So, the ideal order would be:

1. Split
2. SMOTEN
3. Encoding

Assuming you use sklearn-compatible routines, you should fit the transformers on train set only and use those to transform both train and test sets.